# Clarifying the plot command in R

Tags: r, plot, svm

I'm following [this](http://cbio.ensmp.fr/~jvert/svn/tutorials/practical/svmbasic/svmbasic_notes.pdf) tutorial to implement a support vector machine in R.

I'm having trouble clarifying the working of the plot command

```
plot(x,col=ifelse(y>0,1,2))
```

x is of size 300 as `length(x)` confirms, but `length(ifelse(y>0,1,2)` shows 150.

How is the plot working then, if there are 300 x values but only 150 y values?

When I tried

`plot(x,ifelse(y>0,1,2))` it shows the expected error ie,

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

What is it about `col=ifelse(y>0,1,2)` that makes it work?

Comment: Make sure that `length(y)` equals `length(x)`. Some y-coords seem to be missing and thus the error.

Comment: when `ifelse(y>0,1,2)` is provided to `col` it is recycled to fit the length of `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, R knows recycling, i.e. in many situations R **recycles** vectors if they have not the required length, e.g.

```
1:4 + 1:2
```

The vector `1:2` is recycled, so effectively it becomes `c(1,2,1,2)`
to fit the length of the other vector. Now, we can sum the vectors

```
c(1,2,3,4)  + c(1,2,1,2)
```

The same happens in your example for the `col` argument. The vector `col` is recycled so it fits the length of `x`. **But** as you see, **not all argument values are always recycled** automatically. In the case of the `x` and `y` argument in `plot` this is not the case. This makes sense as it is probably an error, if the length of these two vectors do not match.

Comment: so that works only when the vector is stored in a variable like in col? If we use the output of the `ifelse` directly, it doesn't recycle?

Comment: No, this does not make a difference. Try `plot(1:4, col=1:2);
col <- 1:2; plot(1:4, col=col)`. Both will give you the same result.

Comment: I read your edit, understood it, but still don't get why the latter case is *probably an error* but in case of storing it in `col` it isn't.

Comment: @wrahool if you're not naming your arguments then it's their order that matter: the second argument of `plot` is normally `y=` so your call `plot(x,ifelse(...))` is interpreted as if `ifelse(...)` is the value you're proposing for `y`, not `col`. `col` can be recycled but not `y`.